# findpreference undefined type

Tags: android, dialog, undefined, sharedpreferences, listpreference

I am trying to set a value to a ListPreference and always get the error message:

```
The method findPreference(String) is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}
```

This is my code:

```
ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) findPreference("enableTranslations");
lp.setValue("");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply call findPreference in wrong place (in OnClickListener).

Call it in method of class that has findPreference method (PreferenceManager or PreferenceActivity) or on object of such type.